# laravel 5 - check if session can be used

Tags: php, session, laravel-5

When a photo is watched on my website, I want to count the views - only if I can block further counting for the current session:

```
    $lp = Session::get('lp',null);

    if(!is_null(Request::cookie('laravel_session')))
    {
        if(is_null($lp) || is_array($lp) && !in_array($pic->id,$lp))
        {
            $cpic = Popularpic::find($pic->id);
            $cpic->hits = $pic->hits + 1;
            $cpic->pop_hits = $pic->pop_hits + 1;
            $cpic->save();
            //increment pic views for showing
            $pic->hits = $cpic->hits;

            Session::push('lp',$pic->id);
        }
    }
```

The problem is, when a user comes directly from another website, the view will not be counted if the cookie is not yet set.

Is there another way to check if I can use `Session`? ..perhaps like this:

```
if(i know i can use session)
   # count
   # session::push
endif
```

I'm trying to count the first view. Before the cookie is set.. ..if it is possible.

Comment: Please re-format your question a bit, no wonder why you don't get any response after 2 hours! Try to explain what you expect, and what doesn't work as expected

Comment: Confuse you question ::: you want to check cookie or session ?

Comment: I want to check for session, like in the second code block. I'm just using the session cookie, because I don't know a better way